# Inter Application Authentication

Tags: java, spring

Question regarding Inter application authentication.
There are 3 web applications.

1. A-A is a liferay spring portlet project
2. B-B is a spring project
3. C-C is a spring project

What I need is C should be accessible to users who clicked a "specific button" in A or B. C applications login details can be can be kept in A and B. But it should not be shown for users. When user click that "specific button" , it will redirect to **authenticated** C application.

**Note :Solution should also support client who disabled Javascript in their browser.**

I think this is common scenario that most of people faced. Can anyone share your experience/approaches?

[image]

C is a third party web application. After user complete process at there browser will be re-redirected to main application(A or B) .

Comment: if these are web applications, can a JSON Web Token work for you? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token

Comment: @ochi thanks.I haven't used that. I will go through on that and update.